# Which editors out of Emacs, Vim and JEdit support multiple simultaneous text insertion points?

Tags: vim, emacs, comparison, text-editor

**Background:** JEdit (and some other text editors as well) support a feature called [Multiple simultaneous text insertion points](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/projects/simuledit/usenix01.html). (at least that's what I'm calling it here).

To understand what this means, take a look at the link.

Out of all the features in use in modern text editors, initial research seems to indicate that this is one feature that *both* Emacs and Vim do not actually support. If correct, this would be pretty exceptional since it's quite difficult to find a text editor feature that has not made its way into at least *one* of these two old-school editors.

**Question:** Has anyone ever seen or implemented this feature in either Emacs, Vim, or both? If so, please point me to a link, script, reference or summary that explains the details.

If you know an alternate way to do the same (or similar) thing, please let me know.

Comment: Useful? That's debatable. Nevertheless the feature seems to be catching momentum in some higher-profile text editors recently, so it's definitely surpassed the level of "purely academic".

Comment: I've been sitting here thinking about all the times I'd use this in my last project...and I wouldn't have.  It really smells like a solution in search of a problem.  Just because other editors are having a feature race doesn't mean it's needed.

Comment: That's interesting. Do you down-vote questions on programming languages that you don't personally use as well? Where did I say this feature is "needed" ... I simply asked if it was out there.

Comment: It's useful. I use it in Eclipse all the time to rename things.

Comment: see https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384250

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719274

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The vim way to do this is the . command which repeats the last change.  So, for instance, if I change a pointer to a reference and I have a bunch of 
  obj->func
that I want to change to 
  obj.func
then I search for obj->, do 2cw to change the obj-> to obj., then do n.n.n. until all the instances are changed.

Perhaps not a flexible as what you're talking about, but it works frequently and is very intuitive and fast when it does.

Comment: I was going to suggest the . command too. It's an amazingly powerful feature!

Answer (score 7):

`moccur-edit.el` almost does what you want.  All the locations matching the regexp are displayed, and the editing the matches makes changes in the corresponding source.  However, the editing is done on a single instance of the occurrence.

I imagine it'd be straight forward to extend it to allow you to edit them all simultaneously (at least in the simple case).

There is a demo of it found [here](http://www.bookshelf.jp/soft/flash/moccuredit.html).

Turns out, the newest versions of moccur-edit don't apply changes in real-time - you must apply the changes.  The changes are also now undoable (nice win).

Answer (score 6):

In EMACS, you could/would do it with `M-x find-grep` and a macro.  If you really insist that it be fully automatic, then you'd include the `find-next` in the macro.

But honestly, this strikes me as a sort of Microsoft-feature: yes, it adds to the feature list, but why bother?  And would you remember it existed in six months, when you want to use it again?

Answer (score 4):

For emacs, [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) does exactly that.

Have a look at [emacsrocks episode 13](http://emacsrocks.com/e13.html), by the author of the module.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this feature has a direct analogue in either Emacs or Vim, which is not to say that everything achievable with this feature is not possible in some fashion with the two 'old-school' editors.  And like most things Emacs and Vim, power-users would probably be able to achieve such a task exceedingly quickly, even if mere mortals like myself could spend five minutes figuring out the correct grep search and replace with appropriate back-references, for example.

Answer (score 3):

[YASnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) package for Emacs uses it. See 2:13 and 2:44 in the [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOj7btx3ATg).

Answer (score 2):

Another slight similarity: In Emacs, the rectangle editing features provided by `cua-selection-mode` (or `cua-mode`) automatically gives you multiple insertion points down the left or right edge of the marked rectangle, so that you can type a common prefix or suffix to all of those lines.

e.g.:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `cua-selection-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> (enable the global minor mode, if you don't already use this or cua-mode)
<kbd>C-RET</kbd> <kbd>down</kbd> <kbd>down</kbd> <kbd>down</kbd> (marks a 1x3 character rectangle)
*type prefix here*
<kbd>C-RET</kbd> (unmark the rectangle to return to normal editing)

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this in vim:

```
%s/paint.\((.*),/\1.paint(/
```

Or something like that, I am really bad at "mock" regular expressions.

The idea is substitute the pattern:

```
/paint(object,/
```

with

```
/object.paint(/
```

So, yes, it is "supported"

Answer (score 1):

It seemed simple to do a basic version of this in Emacs lisp.  This is for when you just want two places to insert text in parallel:

```
(defun cjw-multi-insert (text)
  "insert text at both point and mark"
  (interactive "sText:")
  (insert-before-markers text)
  (save-excursion
    (exchange-point-and-mark)
    (insert-before-markers text)))
```

When you run it, it prompts for text and inserts it at both point (current position) and mark.  You can set the mark with `C-SPC`.  This could be easily extended for N different positions. A function like `set-insert-point` would record current position (stored as an Emacs [marker](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overview-of-Markers.html#Overview-of-Markers)) into a list and then when you run the multi-insert command, it just iterates through the list adding text at each.

I'm not sure about what would a simple way to handle a more general "multi-editing" feature.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. This would be quite difficult to do with a primarily console-based UI.

That said, there is similar features in vim (and emacs, although I've not used it nearly as much) - search and replace, as people have said, and more similarly, column insert mode: http://pivotallabs.com/users/brian/blog/articles/350-column-edit-mode-in-vi