# How to edit multiple locations simultaneously in Vim

Tags: vim

In certain text editors, like E, I can select multiple locations and, as I type, all the selected locations get replaced with the characters I am typing.

For example if I have:

```
<tag1 class=""></tag1>
<tag2><tag3 class=""></tag3></tag2>
```

In E I could select two locations inside sets of quotations marks then start typing and both locations would be updated simulataneously.  In Vim, I can select several connected columns at once and then edit them, but I'm wondering if there is any way to select multiple locations that aren't lined up.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by "all the selected locations"? Are these selected locations all in the same shape, like a column? Or do they all contain the same initial text?

Comment: @Greg - I've edited the question to clarify.  Hope that helps.

Comment: to me, this feature is more like search and replace but in a more fancy way

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [SnippetsEmu](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1318).  It should be doing something very similar to what you need.

It emulates TextMates snippets.  You should be able to have one snippet with the same tag repeated, and editing will do the right thing, updating the same tag in all locations, as you type.

Comment: It turns out that Ayman you are exactly correct!  There is also another script called snipMate that does this as well.  See the screen cast referenced here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540.  It is almost identical to the screencast features demoed in e.

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I would probably edit those particular lines (there are many ways):

```
/""<enter>
aText to replace...<esc>
n
.
```

First, search for the empty quotes to put the cursor on the first one. Using the "a" (append) command, type the new text to put inside the quotes. When you're done, use "n" (next) to go to the next instance, and "." (repeat last command) to insert the same text again. Repeat the "n ." as many times as necessary.

This method takes less up-front preparation and lets you get started right away without identifying ahead of time all the locations where you might want to add the text.

Comment: That definitely a good way to get text around quickly.  However, that isn't an example of simultaneous editing in the same way that e does it.  Perhaps this is the 'vim' way of doing things (and as you indicate has the advantage that you don't need to know all places ahead of time).

Comment: Vim can't do simultaneous edits (possible it can be emulated through vimscript). Setting up a repeatable command is a bit more work IMO, but it's the way to do it Vim.

Comment: I want to add that the command on the second line can be any other vim action like:

5x, i<some_text>

Comment: @Svend I'm relatively new to vim, and surprised to learn it can't do simultaneous edits (it seems to have a way to do just about everything)

Comment: @stevec That comment is also over 13 years old, and plenty of development has happened with vim since then, and since I've not used vim for nearly just as long, I would no longer place any value in that comment. A quick google seems to indicate that there's ways this can be done now a days, but also like my comment indicates, this might "behave" differently then multi-cursors/edits are implemented in common editors these days.

Comment: @Svend okay, really appreciate the reply. I'll do a little more research and try and sus it out

Answer (score 6):

You may be looking for visual mode blockwise, which will allow insertion, deletion etc on several lines at once.

Blockwise mode will allow square selections with the column and line of the initial point in one corner, and the current cursor position defining the column and line of the other corner. This, as opposed to the line based selection that is the default.

CTRL-v will place you in blockwise visual mode.

If you have several lines like so:

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES(1, 'Jim');
INSERT INTO Users VALUES(2, 'Jack');
INSERT INTO Users VALUES(3, 'Joseph');
```

And wanted to insert "0," after the id for each line, then place the cursor after the comma in the first line:

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES(1,* 'Jim');
```

With the asterisk representing the cursor the command sequence would be:

```
CTRL-v  # Put into blockwise visual mode
j       # Down a line
j       # Down a line
CTRL-I  # Captial I for insert
0,      # the text to insert
Esc     # escape
```

The text should now look like:

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES(1, 0, 'Jim');
INSERT INTO Users VALUES(2, 0, 'Jack');
INSERT INTO Users VALUES(3, 0, 'Joseph');
```

Also blockwise visual mode, x will delete a selection, y will yank it.

:help CTRL-V will give further documentation.

Comment: The limitation with CTRL-v is that it only does contiguous blocks, if the text you want to edit isn't lined up nicely in a column, you can't use it!

Comment: Ah, in that case you have me. There is a multiselect plugin, but I have never used it:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953

Comment: Is it really `<C-I>`, not `<C-i>`?

Comment: `CTRL-I` doesn't give you capital `I`.

Answer (score 2):

For your example I would use a substitution:

```
:%s/class=""/class="something"/g
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  However, my question is not about finding any solution to the admittedly contrived example but actually about solving the example using simultaneous editing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for something like that, more specifically a very useful functionality from ST2, where you press <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> to select next occurrence and then replace both occurrence by just typing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors).

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> as many times as necessary to select the multiple occurences.